# MySQL rolling backups

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I want to backup MySQL hourly, but only keep one days worth of backups and the. Start the process again.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [twindb-backup](https://github.com/twindb/backup) configure retention policy like this

```
[retention]
hourly_copies=24
daily_copies=1
weekly_copies=0
monthly_copies=0
yearly_copies=0
```

The rest is per documentation on http://twindb-backup.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html#configuration

I would also recommend to do daily full copies (`full_backup=daily`) and incremental every hour.

Comment: That looks perfect, cheers :)